# How to test Flutter + Native flows

Tags: flutter

I notice that Flutter's test driver supports only flutter-related elements. Android testing supports only native elements interactions and I'm interested to know on how to test user flows that requires both interactions.

E.g.: Flutter Button Clicked => Native pictures gallery widget shown => simulate select image => Check Image is loaded